# What is the error in my query?

Tags: php, mysql

in below query it returns 12 record while query in from clause (as t) returns 18 record, can anyone help what is the issue in this query?

```
SELECT count(abc.id) as total_this_month,t.* 
FROM email_details abc
JOIN
(SELECT count(email_details.id) as total_emails,MAX(`email_details`.email_date) as email_date1, `email_details`.* FROM (`cld_users` join email_details on email_details.fk_user_id = cld_users.id) GROUP BY `email_details`.`email_title` ORDER BY `email_details`.`email_date` DESC) as t 
ON abc.email_title = t.email_title
where (MONTH(abc.email_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(abc.email_date)=YEAR(NOW()))
group by  t.email_title
ORDER BY t.`email_date` DESC
```

Comment: whats the error you get when you run the query?

Comment: tell us the error first

Comment: i need all 18 rows return by query in form clause

Comment: yes but are there any errors?

Comment: the error is the difference in number of rows

Comment: no it return result but instead of 18 iy gives 12 record

Comment: You have a query that returns 18 records. You embed this in another query and apply a where clause and a group by. So yes, the number of rows might be less that 18.

Comment: i need if count has 0 even then it should show me row

Comment: without the data it is hard to tell what is going on

Comment: "i need if count has 0 even then it should show me row" This is totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: please show your error

Comment: only those records are being shown where the value of total_this_month is > 0

Comment: @ImranQamer Please, provide sql fiddle with sample data and your query

Comment: Instead of providing small pieces of information one at a time in comments, rewrite your question so that people get a chance to understand what you're up to. You need help, we shouldn't have to beg for information.

Comment: ok listen i need all 18 rows from t plus i need count(abc.id) for all those rows.

Comment: anyone got idea now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you specify

```
where (MONTH(abc.email_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(abc.email_date)=YEAR(NOW()))
```

But in the subquery (the one returning 18 results), you have 6 emails with a month that is not december 2014. There's no way that those emails can be returned by a query that explicitly excludes them.

You want those emails as well so you get 18 results ? Remove the `WHERE` clause excluding them:

```
SELECT Count(abc.id) AS total_this_month,
       t.*
FROM   email_details abc
       JOIN (SELECT Count(email_details.id)         AS total_emails,
                    Max(`email_details`.email_date) AS email_date1,
                    `email_details`.*
             FROM   (`cld_users`
                     JOIN email_details
                       ON email_details.fk_user_id = cld_users.id)
             GROUP  BY `email_details`.`email_title`
             ORDER  BY `email_details`.`email_date` DESC) AS t
         ON abc.email_title = t.email_title
GROUP  BY t.email_title
ORDER  BY t.`email_date` DESC
```

Starting from there, if you want to count the emails from the current month, simply replace:

```
SELECT Count(abc.id) AS total_this_month,
```

with

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(abc.email_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(abc.email_date)=YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_this_month,
```

Comment: i put where clause to get count of current month, if i remove that then what should i write to get count of current month.?

Comment: That's not the way you should do it

Comment: Thanks solved my problem, now just i have to recheck that if result is correct or not.Thanks again.